# IndexError: list index out of range using TimeDistrbuted with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement a CNN + RNN application to play a game. The network is supposed to take an image as input an produce an array of controller commands as outputs.

I found out that, in order to get to RNN work, I need to use TimeDistribute layer for my CNN part ([Source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/)). As I was drafting the model, I found out that it throwed IndexError, even though the dimensions should be correct.

Here's code to reproduce the error:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
import numpy as np

training_x = np.random.rand(1,320,240,1)  # (n,x,y,c)
training_y = np.random.rand(5)

m = Sequential()
m.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(10, 10), input_shape=(320,240,1))))
m.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(4, 4)))
m.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
m.add(LSTM(10))
m.add(Dense(5))
m.compile(optimizer='Adam')
m.fit(training_x, training_y)
```

I use tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0, Keras 2.2.2 with windows 10

full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\app\utils\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    m.fit(training_x, training_y)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 950, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 671, in _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(x)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 577, in _set_inputs
    self.build(input_shape=(None,) + inputs.shape[1:])
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 225, in build
    x = layer(x)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py", line 248, in call
    y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 168, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3565, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 779, in convolution
    data_format=data_format)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 828, in __init__
    input_channels_dim = input_shape[num_spatial_dims + 1]
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 615, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include the full error trace

Comment: @desertnaut Done.

Comment: Please update your code - as it is now, it gives a different error (`ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an 'input_shape' or 'batch_input_shape' argument`.

Comment: @desertnaut I doublechecked that code, and it gives me the error above.

Comment: You sure have not changed it to `m.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(10, 10)), input_shape=(320,240,1)))` (i.e. moving `input_shape` outside of `Conv2D` definition)?

Comment: @desertnaut No. The input_shape is in Conv2D. I also tested by moving it to the TimeDistributed layer, which threw the same IndexError.

Comment: I am having the same issues.  Was this ever resolved?  I am, instead, using Conv1D with training set shape (39, 4,1) --- each of the 39 elements in the set is an array of 4 elements from a singular sequence shifted by 1 element, and input_shape = (4,1).

Comment: No it wasnt solved